# comando psql no prompt. (Banco postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou tentando fazer um script com extensão .bat pra fazer update automático no banco,Só que, pra fazer isso preciso saber como informar a senha do meu banco através de comando.

estou fazendo da seguinte forma pra acessar o meu banco através do pronpt do windows.
psql -U usuario do banco -w senha do banco

porém recebo a seguinte mensagem 
fe_sendauth:no passoword supplied

OBS:sei que ao digitar( psql -U usuario do banco ) ele pede a senha mas, é justamente isso que quero que nao apareça.Quero informar a senha por comando.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Crie um arquivo de senhas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) contendo uma linha como

```
*:*:teste:postgres:senha
```

O arquivo tem que ser `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`

Para descobrir qual é o diretório `%APPDATA%` digite no prompt:

```
echo %APPDATA%
```

Comment: É exatamente isso mas ainda não entendi como fazer e como usar.Poderia ser mais claro

Comment: @thiagoxavier Depois que você criar o arquivo não vai mais precisar informar a senha. Não precisa fazer nada. O que exatamente você não entendeu? Como criar o arquivo?

Comment: SIm, é a estrutura do bloco  no caso eu fiz assim: *:*localhost:5432:teste:postgres:123  seguindo a estrutura Hostname : port : database : username : password mas quando vou pra o prompt e digito psql -U postgres ele ainda pede a senha   estou editando o arquivo txt que fica na pasta  C:\Users\Thiago\AppData\Roaming\postgresql

Comment: @thiagoxavier Use a linha exatamente como eu postei.

Comment: valeu obrigado deu certo.Desculpa nao ter entendido antes

Answer (score 3):

Sempre vinha a pergunta da senha ***postgres*** nos meus exemplos também...

Então no meu `.BAT` criei uma linha com o seguinte comando:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=postgres
```

(senha do meu exemplo é ***postgres***, não precisou de aspas nem nada...)

depois disso, adicionei nova linha no .bat para executar o comando que eu precisava da seguinte forma, e não me questionou senha:

```
echo on
C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe -h LOCALHOST -U postgres -d nomedabasedados -c "Update nometabela  set dt_atualizacao = LOCALTIMESTAMP where cod_oper = %OPERADORA% "
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione -w, conforme segue:

```
psql -d mydb -U myuser -W
```

Comment: mas se eu digitar do jeito que esta ai vai ser pedido senha.Quero saber se tem um comando que passe a senha e ele execute direto sem aparecer a mensagem "senha  pra usuario postgres".

Comment: adicione ao seu comando o "-W"

Comment: fiz desse jeito mas ainda pede a senha. Tambem coloquei -w senha. editei o documento logo acima

Answer (score 0):

Atualize o arquivo pg_hba.conf, adicione a linha

"host    all             postgres             127.0.0.1/32            trust"

Assim sua conexão local host com o usuário postgres não vai pedir senha

O -W força pedir senha, isso não te ajuda em nada.

Pra min essa alteração funcionou.

No mais se você estiver usando um .bat para conectar, você pode adicionar as seguintes variáveis ao seu script

Essa faz o script não pedir usuário

set PGUSER=postgres

Essa faz o script não pedir senha

set PGPASSWORD=postgres

Answer (score -2):

Consulte a página https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-envars.html Está tudo lá. Exemplo:

```
cls
SET PGPASSWORD=postgres
SET PGUSER=postgres
SET PGHOST=LOCALHOST
SET PGDATABASE=unico

psql.exe -c "select nome from entidade"
```